# htaccess redirect from index page in subfolder to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a folder in my webroot called Country. I have an index.html page in this subfolder. If I type in domain.com/country, I get domain.com/app/webroot/country/.
If I type in the '/' after country, I get domain.com/country/ which is what I need. How can I redirect using htaccess from domain.com/country to domain.com/country/

I would like the rule to be only for the country folder. I have the following rule, but it applies to the whole site, which I don't want.

```
    RewriteEngine on
# index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root folder of your domain, ahead of any other rules you have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if country does not have a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/country$ [NC]
#redirect to country with a trailing slash
RewriteRule . /country/ [L,R=301]
```